# Azure NSG blocking traffic to docker container

Tags: azure, docker

I have an Azure VM running Ubuntu. For this VM, I've set up a network security group rule to allow TCP traffic on ports 9200-9300. The allowed sources are my VPN's IP, and the IP of another VM. It's entered as a comma seperated list of IP's like `123.456.789,654.432.321`. See below:

[image]

On this VM, I have a docker container running for ElasticSearch. It is listening on port 9200. If I SSH into the VM, and `curl localhost:9200`, I get a JSON as a response which is what I want.

[image]

After this, I open my browser, and go to `VM-IP:9200`, but I get a "This site can't be reached" message, where I would expect a JSON response. If I change the NSG rule to allow traffic from any IP `*` I encounter the same issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying to access Ubuntu VM 9200 port using browser from VPN's IP and not public IP?

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. Yes, I'm connected to my VPN. My SSH port is also set to only allow traffic from my VPN's IP, and I can succesfully SSH into the machine. I have also tried to remove the IP constraint from my NSG rule and am still running into the same issue.

Comment: It seems in container elasticsearch is mapped with localhost 
Try to run command on Host machine. 
$ sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Comment: Try to check elastic config /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml if IP is not linked to 127.0.0.1

network :
    host : 127.0.0.1  //or ifconfig (ex eth0 : IP)

Comment: Do you ssh into the VM with its private IP? I mean the VM-IP you use to access port 9200?

Comment: @AndriyBilous I have performed the vm.max_map_account command, the config file is not present in that location. I did find `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml`, and if I `cat` it I get `cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0`


@CharlesXu yes I can.

Comment: What about the NSG inbound rule looks like? I can't see the source. What do you set for the source?